# Dialogs in Skill Bot- Microsoft Bot Framework v4- NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I am working on a Chatbot on Microsoft Bot Framework V4 in Nodejs. The bot has one Skill Consumer and two Skills with LUIS and QnA integrated. I have some dialogs on one Skill bot that I am triggering through `SkillDialog` from the parent bot. Dialog in the skill bot uses some prompts to take input from the user. Now I am able to trigger the dialog from root bot but after giving input to a prompt the flow goes back to the root bot and QnA gets triggered.
I am wrapping the QnA logic inside `if(!context.responded){Dialog and QnA Logic}`

Comment: Wanted an understanding whether you are looking for anything in specific?

Comment: I dont want the flow go to the root bot once the dialog mode is activated

Comment: Are you using adaptive dialogs or Composer by any chance? I wonder if [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/3848#issuecomment-674274470) might shed some light on your issue. (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @PrashantAgarwal - Are you still working on this?